# In RVM, gem list command does not show installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

In my rails application

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
```

When I run

```
rvm gemset list
```

It specifies my gemset which i'm using

```
   global
=> blackapp
```

now i do bundle install and gems are installed successfully.when i do gem list, it shows *** LOCAL GEMS *** as empty.When i run rvm gem list  it shows all the gems.So what could be the reason that gem list is not working.

I think I used bundle pack and that could be the reason as it shows .

```
 Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: i did bundle list and then run bundle install.Now gem list shows the gems.thanx for replies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bundle install` will install the gems to the `vendor/cache` directory within a rails app, which does not install them in the gems directory.  To list the gems installed by bundler, use `bundle list`

Answer (score 3):

use `gem list --local` instead of using `gem list local`

Comment: if you want to install gems to your system try to use `bundle install --system`

Comment: when you use RVM and you want to install gems into your gemset - use `gem install *gemname*`, and if you want install gems into your Rails app use - `bundle install --path vendor/bundle_gems`

Answer (score 0):

you also have to make sure you have selected your specific gemset you want the gems installed into. I see that you did this, but this is the number one reason for 'disappearing' gems. People forget to select the gemset prior to doing the install of gems, then end up installed in the 'default' gemset (which is used when no gemset is selected), and then they select their gemset and wonder why they're not there.

Also, do NOT use rvm to install to system. System rubies are NOT managed at ALL by RVm and the only reason why RVM supports

```
rvm use system
```

is simply to allow people to select the system ruby. RVM is not and will not be responsible for changes to the system ruby and its environment as this is usually managed by the OS's package manager. Using RVM to manage this is a Bad Idea(Tm) as a result.